# Setting global variable inside nested ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nested

I have a specific requirement with nested ajax calls. I am trying to set a globally accessible variable inside success of one ajax call and this ajax call is being invoked inside success of another ajax call. Eventually the parent success method of parent ajax call utilizes the global variable to perform further operations. The problem is that the value of global variable always remains blank. It works if I make the second ajax request as async:false; but this solution defeats the very purpose of using ajax in the first place.

Let me share a small sample code to illustrate my problem:

```
//global variables
var xURL = "https://sampleurl.com";
var glblID = "";

//first ajax call    
$.ajax({    
   url: url1,    
   data: data1,
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function (msg) {
      //some js code here

      //second ajax call
      FetchID();

      //more js code here

      if(glblID != "")
      {
          window.location.href = xURL + "?id=" + glblID 
      }
      else
      {
          window.location.href = xURL;
      }
   }
});

function FetchID()
{
    $.ajax({
       url: url2,
       data: data2,
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (data) {
           glblID = data.d;
       }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Why can't you move your `if(glblID ...` logic from the first `success` callback to the `success` callback inside `FetchID`?

Comment: Welcome. `$.ajax` is asynchronous. You can return the result from `$.ajax` and then use `.then(function(result) { // use result here })` (or `.done(...)`) from your calling function. You should probably learn about promises while you're at it.

Comment: @Franck Modica I'm pretty sure he wants his `FetchID` function to not have side effects and just retrieve a value.

Comment: @Jeto yeah that makes sense

Comment: @Jeto thanks for your suggestion. Probably that would be the way forward i.e. to learn about promise. For now I am trying solution by ponury-kostek.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem using suggestion by @jeto and ponury-kostek. I studied and got introduced to the wonderful world of Promise. I tried the plain Javascript version with  bluebird js for compatibility with IE.

Answer (score 1):

> As of `jQuery 1.5` implement the `Promise` interface, giving them all
>   the properties, methods, and behavior of a `Promise`

```
//first ajax call    
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    data: data1,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
}).then(function (msg) {
    //second ajax call
    FetchID().then((data) => {
        var glblID = data.d;
        if (glblID != "") {
            //do something with glblID
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    });
});

function FetchID() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        data: data2,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ponury-kostek; I tried your solution but it did not work. I guess it was my fault that I didn't present the complete picture. I have updated my post with the exact scenario. Would you be able to help with it?